# Using the same component template and updating the API data

Tags: api, vue.js, vue-component, axios

I'm building a page that has a embeds a specific twitch stream video. I'm only displaying one video at the top of my page.

Twitch has an embed code that allows you to grab the channel you want to watch and it will display the embedded video and chat. It requires a div id to target the DOM to add the embedded video.

https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed/everything/

My problem is when I click on another page, that uses the same template, it doesn't replace the video. Rather, it adds another IFRAME embed video to the id. So every time I click on the page, it just adds another video to the div id.

I'm using the watch function to update other elements of the page. So when I click on another page, using the same template, the data updates correctly. Everything works and updates except for that embed video.

Is there a way to clear out that div id every time I click another another page? I apologize in advance. I've only been learning Vuejs for a couple of weeks now, and it's all rather new to me.

Here is why my template looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="video heading-title container">

      <div class="streamWrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div v-for="live in streams" class="col-12 stream-card">
            <div class="twitch-vid-wrapper">
              <div id="twitch-embed"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

import appService from '../service.js'
import '../embedTwitch.min.js' // twitch video embed script

export default {
  name: 'Video',
  data: function() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      streams: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getFirstLiveStream()
    this.getLiveStreams()
  },
  watch: {
      '$route' (to, from) {
      this.id = to.params.id
      this.getLiveStreams()
      this.getFirstLiveStream()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getLiveStreams(game){
      game = this.$route.params.id;
      appService.getLiveStreams(game).then(data => {
        this.live = data
      });
    },
    getFirstLiveStream(game) {
      game = this.$route.params.id;
      appService.getFirstLiveStream(game).then(data => {
        this.streams = data
        let channelName = this.streams[0].channel.display_name

        appService.getTwitchStream(channelName)
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the method I have in my service:

```
const appService = {
    getFirstLiveStream(game) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            axios.get('/kraken/streams/?sort=views&stream_type=live&game='+game)
            .then((response) => {
                 // send variables to calc the offset
                 var total = response.data._total;
                 var query = this.calculateSingleOffset(game, total)
                 resolve(query)
            })
        })
    },
    getTwitchStream(channel) {
       return setTimeout(function(){ 
            new Twitch.Embed('twitch-embed', {
                width: '100%',
                height: 480,
                channel: channel
            });
        }
      , 500);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, what you need is how to assign different id for one twitch template inside each instance of the component.

**The solution:**

1. add one data property like `twitchId`
2. simply uses `Date.now()` to generate unique id (this method is just one demo, you can use own methods to get one ID).
3. then bind `<div :id="twitchId">` which will embed into twitch video.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

function embedContent(elementId) {
  let contents = ['I am a test', 'nothing', 'connecting', 'bla bla ...', 'Puss in boots', 'Snow White']
  document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = '<p>' + contents[Math.floor(Math.random()*contents.length)] + '</p>'
}

Vue.component('twitch', {

  template: `<div class="video">
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    <div :id="twitchId"></div>
  </div>`,
  props: ['name'],
  data() {
    return {
      twitchId: ''
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.twitchId = Date.now().toString(16)
  },
  mounted: function () {
    embedContent(this.twitchId)
  }
})

app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    videos: [
      'channel 1',
      'World Cup for Football',
      'StackOverFlow'
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.video {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <twitch v-for="(item, index) in videos" :name="item" :key="index"></twitch>
  </div>
</div>
```